# Fill array of random rumbers to sum in excel vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, random, sampling

I'm trying to create a sampling tool for which

I need to pick randomly generated numbers between 0 and 3000 in multiples of 500 such that their sum is a fixed number say 10000 in 12 slots

Over to that I need to run multiple iterations about 100000 to 1000000 (not decided yet.

My approach is to create a two dimensional array, put a constraint to validate the sum total of an iteration, and only if the condition is true enter it in the final data sample.

I'm making some very terrible mistakes with the following code could not figure out where... Help is appreciated

```
Public Sub Generatenums()
    Dim GRP() As Long, Random() As Long
    Dim RandomTotal As Long, t As Long, w As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    ReDim GRP(1 To 100, 1 To 12)
    ReDim Random(1 To 12)

    For i = 1 To 100
        For j = 1 To 12
            Random(j) = Int(Rnd() * 7) * 500
            RandomTotal = RandomTotal + Random(j)
        Next j

        If RandomTotal = 10000 Then
            For k = 1 To 12
                GRP(i, k) = Random(k)
            Next k
        End If
    Next i

    Range("A1").Select
    For t = 1 To 100
        For w = 1 To 12
            Cells(t, w).Value = GRP(t, w)
        Next w
    Next t
End Sub
```

Comment: First off, you should probably rewrite this with a nested for loop, instead of hardcoding 1, 2, 3... 12.

Comment: I can try that taking a variable j from 1 to 12. I agree it makes the program less clunky

Comment: It also makes it more readable in general, which might help you (or someone else) diagnose the problem easier.  Also, what is RandomTotal currently being used for?

Comment: RandomTotal is a variable to validate that the sum of the row must be restricted to 10000... i realise it was missing from the code posted earlier

Comment: Alright, that's better.  However, currently, if your sum isn't right, you just move on to the next value of i without ever filling in values to that row of GRP.  You have a few options.  You can loop inside your first loop to keep generating numbers until the sum is 10000. Or you could try to come up with an algorithm that guarantees that the sum of your numbers is 10000.  (I have to warn you, 12 numbers summing to 10000 gives each number an average value of about 833, but randomly generating numbers between 0 and 3000 gives you and average per number of 1500, almost twice what you want!)

Comment: randomize 11 values, then subtract their total from 10,000 to get the 12th. If this last one isn't in your range, you will have to start again, but it's going to produce results a little quicker than generating all 12.

Comment: Thanks sean, but that would skew the observation towards the first  11 values. One of the reasons i considered random numbers was because it give normal distribution, or "fair chance" that will give me a better representation of the samples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fantom, welcome to SO.

The commentors are right: This will take a very long time to run.

Instead of thinking of this as an array to fill as a certain sum, think of it as a Pachinko or [Galton Board](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaltonBoard.html) with 20 balls bouncing around and ending up in bins at the bottom. Why 20? Because you want a sum of 10000 in increments of 500, and consider 10000/500 = 20 as one ball.

Now the program can run in linear time. You don't randomize the sums, you randomize which of the 12 slots the ball will fall into. Then you multiply how many balls are in each slot by 500 and your sum will always be 10000.

One of the loops looks like this:

```
For i = 1 To 20
  x = Rnd() * 12 + 1
  If x > 12 Then x = 12
  If x < 1 Then x = 1
  bin(x) = bin(x) + 1
Next i
```

Is that enough to solve your problem, or do you need some more?

Comment: In the calculation of `x = Rnd() * 12 + 1`, for 100 runs, the 12th bin is always the largest and the first bin is always the smallest. If you take off the +1, the 12th bin is always the smallest and the first bin is always the biggest. Using 0.5 seems to smooth it out.

Comment: Thanks rajah, its your suggested approach is certainly refreshing, according to you what would be the best way to limit a bin size to 6  as the total value in a single bin should not exceed 3000

Comment: Also solving through array seems to reduce the time taken  hardly 3 mins for 100K iterations.

Comment: It makes sense that it's running faster. That's what I meant by "linear time." As to limiting to 6, I think you might change the loop above from a for loop to a do while. Have it count up from 1, and increment every time it fills a bin. Check bin(x) before you fill it, and if it's 6 or bigger, skip the loop without incrementing.

Comment: Thanks so much Rajah its already working Couldn't have done it without your help. i'll upload the actual code for everyone's reference as well.

Comment: If you're doing a simulation, I would suggest that you graph the averages of the bins. You will see evidence of some unusual distributions. Changing the code to Rnd() * 12 + .5 would seem to be prudent. BTW, I appreciate the upvote. If you click "Accept" I will get another virtual "payment."